# Assign sticky bit to linux group permissions using python

Tags: python, linux, sticky, chmod

Is there a way I can get sticky bit for a folder group permissions using python?
I am aware of it how its done it linux:

```
chmod g+s <folder_name>
```

I would like to use python way in the code for doing the same. 
I looked at `os.chmod()` too, but didnt seem to figure out a way to to set sticky bit. 
Any pointers would help.

Answer (score 1):

found this after a lot of trials and searching on web:

```
os.chmod(dirname, 02755)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
#dirname = "foodir"
os.mkdir(dirname, 0o2700)
os.chmod(dirname, 0o2700)
```

Shell equivalent:

```bash
chmod 700 foodir
chmod g+s foodir
```